# Getting SVN commit messages for a certain month?

Tags: svn

I have some bash scripts that generate beautiful reports; however, as the project has become larger, and gone on for longer and longer, the time it takes to generate the reports has gotten longer as well.  I am looking for a way to have svn give me all of the commit messages for a certain month.  I currently just loop through all of the messages from 0 to the current version.  Is there a way to get the commit messages for a specific month using SVN?  I can do it with scripts, but I've been looking for a more direct method first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVN log command [supports](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html) date arguments. Command below will return all revisions made in April plus one last revision made in March.

```
svn log -r '{2016-04-01}':{'2016-04-30'}
```

Comment: And I thought that I did a good job of reading the instructions, oops.